# without page reload how to insert the data using below javascript

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

Using  `e.preventDefault();` values not insert in to database,if comment `e.preventDefault();` data inserted in to database, without page reload how to insert the data using below javascript code please suggest me

**Insert form**

```
<form class="form-horizontal msg_fixed_bottom send_message_form"   method="POST" role="form" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Profile_cntrl/supplier_communication"> 
   <div class="panel-footer" id="myForm" >
      <div class="input-group submit_group">
          <input id="messagee" name="messagee" type="text" class="form-control input-sm chat_input" placeholder="Write your message here..." />
             <span class="input-group-btn">
             <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="submit" name="submit">Send</button>
           </span>
       </div>
    </div>
 </form>
```

**script**

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function () {

    scrollDown();

    $("#submit").click(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var message = $("#messagee").val();

        $('#chat_log').append('<div class="row msg_container base_sent active"><div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10"><div class="messages msg_receive"><p>' + message + '</p></div></div></div>');
        $('#messagee').val('');

        scrollDown();
   });
});


function scrollDown() {
  $('.msg_container_base').animate({scrollTop: $('.msg_container_base').prop("scrollHeight")}, 0);
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

## HTML

```
<form id="data_form" class="form-horizontal msg_fixed_bottom send_message_form"> 
<div class="panel-footer" id="myForm" >
    <div class="input-group submit_group">
        <input id="messagee" name="messagee" type="text" class="form-control input-sm chat_input" placeholder="Write your message here..." />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit">Send</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

## JavaScript

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#data_form').on('submit', function(e){
        var form_data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Profile_cntrl/supplier_communication',
              data: form_data,
              success:function(data)
              {
                alert('Success');
              },
              error:function()
              {
                alert('failed');
              }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**insert form**

```
<form class="form-horizontal msg_fixed_bottom send_message_form" id="data_form"  method="POST" role="form" action="#"> 
                                    <div class="panel-footer" id="myForm" >
                                        <div class="input-group submit_group">



                                            <input id="messagee" name="messagee" type="text" class="form-control input-sm chat_input" placeholder="Write your message here..." />


                                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="submit" name="submit">Send</button>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
```

**javascript**

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#data_form').on('submit', function(e){

        var form_data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Profile_cntrl/supplier_communication',
              data: form_data,
              success:function(data)
              {

                 var message = $("#messagee").val();
                    $('#chat_log').append('<div class="row msg_container base_sent active"><div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10"><div class="messages msg_receive"><p>' + message + '</p></div></div></div>');

                    scrollDown();
                    function scrollDown() {
                $('.msg_container_base').animate({scrollTop: $('.msg_container_base').prop("scrollHeight")}, 0);
            }
              },
              error:function()
              {
                alert('failed');
              }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax for submitting the data without page reload.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Ajax post
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".submit").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var messagee= $("input#messagee").val();

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "your_controller/your_function",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                messagee: messagee                    
            },
            success: function(res) {
                if (res) {
                    // Show Entered Value
                   //sussess message here

                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Your Controller:

```
 // This function call from AJAX
public function your_function() {
    $data = array(
    'messagee' => $this->input->post('messagee')    
    );

    //Either you can print value or you can send value to database
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: How can i send the whole form data at once using ajax?

Comment: You can use var **form serialize** like this `str = $( "form" ).serialize();`

Answer (score 0):

**your form:**

```
<form class="form-horizontal msg_fixed_bottom send_message_form" method="POST" role="form" id="msg-form"> 
<div class="panel-footer" id="myForm" >
    <div class="input-group submit_group">
        <input id="messagee" name="messagee" type="text" class="form-control input-sm chat_input" placeholder="Write your message here..." />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </span>
     </div>
</div>
</form>
```

**your ajax**

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#msg-form").submit(function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
           var msg = $("#messagee").val();
           $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Profile_cntrl/supplier_communication',
              data: {msg:msg},
              success:function(data)
              {
                alert('SUCCESS!!');
              },
              error:function()
              {
                alert('fail');
              }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

I think this will work fine. Now add your additional **append** functionality in the success area by yourself. thanks.